# Swagger renders in app.use but not in app.get

Tags: node.js, express, swagger, swagger-ui

I am trying to render a Swagger Document using swagger-ui-express. But only when using app.use, it renders in the browser, but when posting it in app.get, the HTML page is not rendered(blank screen) but the HTML code is generated in response body when I checked in Postman

Below is my code,

`app.use('/api-docs', swaggerUi.serve, swaggerUi.setup(swaggerDoc))`

The above renders the required HTML page.

`app.get('/api-docs', swaggerUi.serve, swaggerUi.setup(swaggerDoc))`

The above generates the HTML code but not rendered in browser, am I missing something ?

Update :

I use the generateHTML method, but it still seems to work the same way,

```
app.use('/api-docs-html/BOOKING-CANCELLATION', function(req, res, next) {
    var pathArraySplit = req.originalUrl.split('/');
    var apiNameWithHyphen = pathArraySplit[2].trim()
    var apiNameWithUnderScore = apiNameWithHyphen.replace('-', '_');
    swaggerDocument = JSONConstructor.JSONConstructorTest(apiNameWithUnderScore)
    swaggerHtml = swaggerUi.generateHTML(swaggerDocument, swaggerUiOpts)
    next()
},swaggerUi.serveFiles(swaggerDocument, swaggerUiOpts))
app.get('/api-docs-html/BOOKING-CANCELLATION', (req, res) => { res.send(swaggerHtml) });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`swaggerUi.serve` is a middleware function so its need to be used with `app.use()`, [Refer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/swagger-ui-express)

Middleware (`app.use()`) and  Route Handler(`app.get()`) are not same function for handling request, [Refer](http://qnimate.com/express-js-middleware-tutorial/)

`next()` call inside a middleware invokes the next middleware or route handler depending on whichever is declared next. But `next()` call inside a route handler invokes the next route handler only. If there is a middleware next then it’s skipped. Therefore middlewares must be declared above all route handlers.

You can use like this as alternative,

```
app.use('/api-docs', swaggerUi.serve);
app.get('/api-docs', swaggerUi.setup(swaggerDocument));
```

Comment: Hi, could you explain a bit more about these swagger middlewares ? I cannot have multiple paths(/api-docs/*) loading different files into swagger-ui.setup()  since always the last gets executed even before the route hit.

Comment: [swagger-ui-express](https://www.npmjs.com/package/swagger-ui-express)
 using [closure](https://github.com/scottie1984/swagger-ui-express/blob/master/index.js#L57) so its generating html on application startup, that's why your getting last generated html. To use multiple docs, Here is the [solution](https://github.com/scottie1984/swagger-ui-express/issues/65)

Comment: Thank you so much, I will explain what I wanna achieve, please let me know if I am looking in the right direction.
1. I have multiple APIs for which I want to host the interactive documentation in a path (say /api-docs/service-name)
2. So depending upon the service-name I want to populate the document(JSON Spec) inside of swaggerUi.setup().

Comment: Yes, Right, So your making multiple documentation depending on service

Comment: Yess. But even in the solution above, I see that it requires the swaggerDocument even before the route is known. I am looking for something like the edit I have added in my question. Even when trying this, only the last generated files are getting viewed even if I have only one route instead of the other, the document that came when I first ran the program is only shown at every instance.

Comment: Your documenting only one URL `req.originalUrl` ? | May be I misunderstood on previous comment, you need to create doc depends on the router you created on overall application ?

Comment: No, there're multiple. I want to repeat the same process of loading the UI based on the URL provided through the same server. Is there any kind of cache I need to clear ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190015/discussion-between-siv-sankr-and-reshma-suresh).